# I2C TinyWireS SEND: How to convert unsigned long to uint8_t array?

Tags: i2c

How do you convert an unsigned long to a `uint8_t` array? I am interested in sending an unsigned long integer from an ATTiny85 to an Arduino Uno via I2C. The issue is with `TinyWireS.Send()` which can only send a var of type `uint8_t`. I believe the solution would be to use `TinyWireS.Send()` in an array?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be politically correct code, but it is pretty simple to just cast a pointer to uint8_t like this:

```
long data = 5;
uint8_t *rx = (uint8_t*) &data;
```

You can still use array subscripts even though its a pointer, and you can pass it to a function like an array. Just don't go past `rx[3]`.

Alternately, you could also make a union like this:

```
union{ long data; uint8_t bytes[4]; } convert;
convert.data = 5;
```

And then use `convert.bytes` as your array to send.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this with an ATtiny You have 32 bit long that needs to be broken up into 4 8-bit chunks. You need to some simple bit shifting to accomplish this.

```
volatile unsigned long Data1;//this is the data you are sending
volatile byte SendCount;
volatile uint8_t sendByte;

void requestEvent()
{  

  SendCount++; //increment this
  switch (SendCount)
  {
    case 1:
      Data1 = GetMyData();
      //Data1 = 55555;
      sendByte = Data1 & 0xFF;
      break;
    case 2:
      sendByte = Data1 >> 8;
      break;
    case 3:
      sendByte = Data1 >> 16;
      break;
    case 4:
      sendByte = Data1 >> 24;
      SendCount=0;
      break;
  }

  TinyWireS.send(sendByte);
}
```

You need to initialize `SendCount = 0;` in your Setup method.

You will need to recompose the 4 bits back into a 32 bit long on the Master device too.